# Conditions combined with logic OR - Swift (error)

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, logical-operators, separator, swift-playground

I`m following a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich
(http://www.raywenderlich.com/81952/intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-1)

This function gives an error. The problem is the line with the logic `OR` operator ( `||` ). I can`t find the cause of the issue.

The function:

```
func turn (degrees: Int) -> String {
    var normalDegrees = degrees
    let degreesInACircle = 360

    if (normalDegrees > degreesInACircle || normalDegrees < -degreesInACircle) {
        normalDegrees = normalDegrees % degreesInACircle
    }

    return "Turn \(normalDegrees) degrees"
}
```

The error I get, says: `Expected "," separator`

The function is a part of a class, but i don´t see why that should be a problem. I´ll upload the code if that is necessary. I´m working with the code in a `playground` file.

The rest of the class:

```
class Vehicle {
    var brandName = ""
    var modelName = ""
    let modelYear = 0
    var powerSource = ""
    var numberOfWheels = 0

    func goForward() -> String {
        return ""
    }

    func goBackwards() -> String {
        return ""
    }

    func stopMoving() -> String {
        return ""
    }

    func turn (degrees: Int) -> String {
        var normalDegrees = degrees
        let degreesInACircle = 360

        if normalDegrees > degreesInACircle || normalDegrees < -degreesInACircle {
            normalDegrees = normalDegrees % degreesInACircle
        }

         return "Turn \(normalDegrees) degrees"
    }

    func changeGears (newGearName: String) -> String {
        return "Put \(modelName) into \(newGearName) gear"
    }

    func makeNoise () -> String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: That code compiles without problems in my Xcode 6 and 7. Please show a (minimal) complete self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Backets as in paranteces? 
The error then says: `Invalid character in source file`
I`ve also tried with paranteces around both the conditions.

Comment: There is probably some problem in the context. Please show a complete class definition, stripped-down as far as possible.

Comment: @MartinR What do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Again, your (updated) code compiles without problems. Are you sure that the error stems from that code? Have you tried to copy it into a fresh project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the if statement is really weird: When something should execute when either the first value is greater than the second or the second is greater than the first, then that's like checking whether the values are indifferent! So

```
if normalDegrees > degreesInACircle || normalDegrees < degreesInACircle
```

is equal to

```
if normalDegrees != degreesInACircle
```

Also you can convert

```
func turn (degrees: Int) -> String {
    var normalDegrees = degrees
```

to

```
func turn (var normalDegrees: Int) -> String {
```

(Is exactly the same, just more concise)

There are some more weird things in your code. What I think you really want is really simple:

```
func turn(degrees: Int) -> String {
    return "Turn \(degrees % 360) degrees"
}
```

(Try it out)

Comment: Hi! It was supposed to be `if normalDegrees > degreesInACircle || normalDegrees < -degreesInACircle` (a minus "-" in front of the `degreesInACircle` in the second condition). I have now changed it, thanks. About the rest of the code, I´m not the creater of it. As mentioned, I am following a tutorial. Therefore, I´m trying to keep my code as close to it as possible. However, thank you for helping!

Comment: I used your code, and it worked perfectly. I guess it won`t hurt the rest of the tutorial, and it helped solving the error. Thank you!